# How can I make standalone cpp files in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Everytime I have to make a new cpp file first I make a new project then add a main.cpp file in source files. Is there a more efficient way like making a new empty file and saving it directly as .cpp?

Comment: You can do that however if you don't have a project you can't build in the ide.

Comment: Yes that is the main question! Is there a workaround this?

Comment: ***Is there a workaround this?*** I say doubtful. How would the IDE guess what type of executable you want?

Comment: I would save the file in cpp format so IDE would know that I am writing a cpp program.

Comment: It will not. Just create a project file as required.

Answer (score 0):

> File -> New File -> Visual C++ -> 'C++ File (.cpp);'

[image: New File Menu]

[image: New File Dialog]

The file can than be saved in a location of your choosing (via `Ctrl + S` or `File -> Save`).

Comment: I am able to make a cpp file but that doesn't compile, it asks me to attach it to some process.